# In qt C++ How i use qcombobox for each row but without pointer? Combo should place in every row

Tags: c++, qt

In qt C++ How i use qcombobox for each row but without pointer? Combo should place in every row?

```cpp
void exampleclass::setComboInRow() 
{
    Qcombobox* combo;

    for(int I=0 ;I<10;I++) 
    {
        combo =new Qcombobox;      //don't want to create new for every row
        ui.tablewidget->setcellwidget(I,0,combo) ;    //is there any other option? 
    }
}
```

Comment: If there are always exactly 10 total comboboxes you could have `std::array<QComboBox>` as a member variable in your `exampleclass` and use `&` to get a pointer. Do not attempt to do that as a local variable in your function because it would no longer exist after the function ends.

Comment: `vector` and `emplace_back`?

Comment: It sounds like the pointer isn't the issue. It's really that you don't want to allocate the combobox on the heap (by using `new`). Maybe try explaining why using `new` is a problem for you?

Comment: @JarMan u r right. I need only one new combo box. But it should show on all row, suppose my rows are created dynamically then this combo box will occupy memory in heap. Thats why I dont want to create new every time.

Comment: You want to create a single combobox and show it on every row? I don't think that will work. Each row needs its own copy. Unless you're saying it will only be visible on row at a time. But I really shouldn't need to try to guess at what you're trying to do. Please give more details in your question.

Comment: You will need a separate QComboBox widget for each row. You can not share the same instance for multiple rows.

Comment: I used signal cellchanged and use setComboInRow() in slot... So by clicking on column combo is showing without for loop..